# ST_GeneratePoints returns the wrong number of points

Tags: postgis, point

I'm using PostGIS to generate random points on some bikeway data sets in my region, and I've run into an issue. For a few of the sets, I find that when I run my query I often don't get the right number of points returned. For example, if I ask for 4 points, I'll receive 3 points. If I increase the radius within which I'm querying, there's a higher chance of this happening (versus a smaller radius, where the query works fine most of the time).

Here's an example query, with a "large" radius:

```sql
SELECT ST_AsText(st_generatepoints) FROM
(SELECT ST_GeneratePoints(geom, 4)
    FROM (
        SELECT ST_Intersection(
            (SELECT ST_Buffer(
                (
                    SELECT ST_Union(geom)
                    FROM bikeways
                    CROSS JOIN (SELECT ST_GeomFromText('SRID=26910;POINT(-122.98054922394947 49.22650820352046)') AS ref_geom) AS r
                    WHERE ST_DWithin(geom, ref_geom, 0.0462677490234375)
                ),
                0.000010, 'endcap=round join=round'
            )),
            (
                SELECT ST_Buffer(
                ST_GeomFromText('SRID=26910;POINT(-122.98054922394947 49.22650820352046)'),
                0.0462677490234375)
            )
        )
        AS geom
    ) AS s
) as p;
```

I assume the way that I'm creating the query is the likely culprit, but being new to PostGIS I'm not sure how I could rewrite it. What kinds of situations would result in `ST_GeneratePoints` returning fewer than the requested number of points?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue...I am using `ST_GeneratePoints` to generate points inside a local planning organizations land use survey overlap with Census block groups, to place one point per person in a residential area, and then measure their distance to an amenity. `ST_GeneratePoints` resulted in the same number of points as the value, 1-2 points more, or 1-2 points fewer. (I used `ST_NumGeometries` to count the points in the MultiPoint geometry created by `ST_GeneratePoints`.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CRS [26910](https://epsg.io/26910) is UTM, with a unit in meters. The coordinates you are using looks a lot like lat-longs (in degrees), and the buffer sizes, if in meters, are rather small (1/100th of a millimeter).

Working with the wrong coordinate system and such small distances, the code is likely being trapped in a precision rounding error.